# Toggling mousetrail on keypress with autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to toggle mouse trails on and off with a keypress (windows key + q) using an autohotkey script, but can't get it working.

This is my code-

```
#q::
if DllCall("SystemParametersInfo", 94) < 2
{
DllCall("SystemParametersInfo", UInt, 0x005E, UInt, 0, UInt, 9, UInt, 0)
}else {
DllCall("SystemParametersInfo", UInt, 0x005E, UInt, 0, UInt, 0, UInt, 0)
}
return
```

Are you able to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First read the value using SPI_**GET**MOUSETRAILS into a variable by reference (`intP`) then set the new value using SPI_**SET**MOUSETRAILS:

```c
#q::
    DllCall("SystemParametersInfo", int,SPI_GETMOUSETRAILS:=0x5E, int,0, intP,length, int,0)
    length := length > 1 ? 0 : 9
    DllCall("SystemParametersInfo", int,SPI_SETMOUSETRAILS:=0x5D, int,length, int,0, int,0)
    return
```