# How to create a custom ghost trail of mouse cursor?

Tags: c#

I would like to create a custom ghost trail across the operating system. I know that [CursorFX](https://www.stardock.com/products/cursorfx) has a feature like this. Is there a Windows API to accomplish this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Toggling mousetrail on keypress with autohotkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32909204/toggling-mousetrail-on-keypress-with-autohotkey).  Specific c# use of the function is described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434709/using-systemparametersinfo-from-c-sharp-spi-getscreenreader-spi-setscreenreader)